# 3 голоса "против" одновременно по разным темам

Tags: поддержка, голоса-против

18.04.18 (то есть на момент публикации позавчера) в 16:10-16:11 получил 3 голоса "против" на разные вопросы по разным темам

[image: Серийное голосование]

После 24х часов эти голоса не откатились. Можно ли что-то предпринять в данной ситуации со стороны модераторов или управляющего сообществом?

Comment: Да, там устроена система, три голоса еще не серия.

Comment: Можно на мете вопрос задать :)

Comment: @FoggyFinder Всё равно это нарушение. Неужели участник в самых разных темах разбирается: [tag:css], [tag:wpf], [tag:asp.net-core]? И все посты (два из которых довольно увесисты) изучил меньше чем за минуту?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov согласен. Btw, мне кажется этот вопрос уже неоднократно поднимался

Comment: Проблему эту как в прошлый раз так и не решили, так и сейчас мало надежд. Выследить каждый его аккаунт, да и уже "умнеть" стал - минусует с интервалом в несколько часов, а система откатывает если только подряд идут голоса + если один\два голоса, то это не считается.

Answer (score 1):

В последние несколько недель завёлся активный минусатор, я приводил в чате примеры из своего опыта, плюс видел, что и других зацепило.

Николас конечно утверждает, что он некоторую работу проводит (и, разумеется, не хочет сдавать нарушителей) - но я вижу как постепенно растёт навык простановки минусов (первые дни - по ответам бил, потом - бесплатно по вопросам, потом стал уменьшать порцию минусов, их уже не откатывают.

Похоже, что кто-то сильно озлобленный таки пошёл фабрику акков пилить.

Я не знаю, что этому противопоставить, кроме того, чтобы отвечать больше, чем накапало минусов.

Но ваш случай вероятно не подпадает под сценарий массового минусования. Три голоса система откатывает, я на днях только [наблюдал](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44009303#44009303). А потому вполне вероятно, что два минуса тихонечко поставил один и тот же мстительный человек, а ещё один прилетел случайно. Или вообще все три прилетели от разных людей, ведь бывает же так?

Comment: "Три голоса система откатывает, я на днях только наблюдал." разве? во всяком случае мне некоторое время назад не откатила

Comment: @FoggyFinder А как вы узнали, что все 3-и минуса были от одного участника?

Comment: @0xdb никак не узнавал, но есть высокая доля вероятности, что если в течении минуты приходит "-" на ответы по списку из профиля, то они поставлены одним участником

Comment: @FoggyFinder ну я тоже думал, что не откатывает, но откатило. Привёл пример в ответе.

Comment: @AK может откатила не система?

Comment: @AK Нет, здесь случайность нереальна. Мне неделями не прилетают голоса против (голоса "за" тоже не сыпятся каждый день, в лучшем случае раз-два в неделю), а тут в течение минуты прилетело. От "разных" людей может только в случае маронеточных аккаунтов, которые в данном случае будут нарушением правил.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov случайность работает не так как люди ожидают. В реальных случайных данных кучкование чаще чем в данных, которые человек генерирует¶ При малом количестве голосов возможны большие относительные отклонения¶ Хотя на своём опыте, на память сразу не приходят случаи, чтобы серийно минуса шли, перед которыми явного конфликта не было. То есть, если был конфликт, а затем минуса появились, то это скорее всего не просто совпадение и если система не откатила голоса, то достойно дальнейшего исследования